# Segmentation Fault when deploying to handset

Tags: android, segmentation-fault

I've got a Galaxy Nexus and today it started to give me a `Segmentation fault` error when deploying to it:

```
[2011-12-07 16:19:17 - Flinders Lite] Android Launch!
[2011-12-07 16:19:17 - Flinders Lite] adb is running normally.
[2011-12-07 16:19:17 - Flinders Lite] Performing com.istudentgroup.flinders.lite.activity.MainMenuActivity activity launch
[2011-12-07 16:19:20 - Flinders Lite] Uploading Flinders Lite.apk onto device '0146914B19021011'
[2011-12-07 16:19:23 - Flinders Lite] Installing Flinders Lite.apk...
[2011-12-07 16:19:25 - Flinders Lite] Success!
[2011-12-07 16:19:25 - Flinders Lite] Starting activity com.istudentgroup.flinders.lite.activity.MainMenuActivity on device 0146914B19021011
[2011-12-07 16:19:26 - Flinders Lite] ActivityManager: Segmentation fault
```

I can open a shell in to the handset and can navigate the directory structure and the phone seems to be operating normally otherwise.

Does anyone know what is going on?  How do I fix it?

Logcat output : http://pastebin.com/VxGdAbap

Comment: Is there anything useful in LogCat around when the activity starts?

Comment: Does your app work in the emulator or on another device? Are you sure it isn't your code?

Comment: yeah, tried different devices, usb lead and code.  have rebooted everything multiple times

Comment: I'm getting this also on my Asus Prime. Was working fine, now for any APK: adb install whatever.apk gives me Segmentation fault...

Comment: do you have any issue with dirver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflashing the [stock image](http://code.google.com/android/nexus/images.html), using tools from the [superboot from modaco](http://android.modaco.com/topic/348161-30-nov-r3-superboot-rooting-the-gsm-lte-galaxy-nexus/) worked.  I used the 4.0.1 (ITL41F) version as this includes the recently released volume bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the Android SDK / ADB / Eclipse recently?
I had a similar problem after an update due to inconsistency between versions.
The problem was corrected after forcing eclipse to check for updates (and install them) of anything that I had installed.

Comment: Not updates recently.  It was literally working and then it stopped.  No reason I can tell as to why.  I'm baffled and thinking it's a hardware issue at this stage

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue.
Make sure your sdk and adt are of latest version.
If the issue still there then its due to the rom installed.

> 1. Some custom roms may leads to this issue.
> 2. Installation of busybox may lead to this issue.
> 3. Corrupted OS installation.

**This can be solved by wiping all data and putting stock rom back.**