# Segmentation Fault in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, fault

I am developing for Android using the adt bundle. When I deploy an app to a device I get a segmentation fault:

```
[2013-01-18 23:24:24 - test2] Android Launch!
[2013-01-18 23:24:24 - test2] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-18 23:24:24 - test2] Performing com.example.test2.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-01-18 23:24:29 - test2] Uploading test2.apk onto device '99000083935364'
[2013-01-18 23:24:30 - test2] Installing test2.apk...
[2013-01-18 23:24:31 - test2] Success!
[2013-01-18 23:24:31 - test2] Starting activity com.example.test2.MainActivity on device 99000083935364
[2013-01-18 23:24:33 - test2] ActivityManager: Segmentation fault
```

I can move the apk to the sdcard and it installs fine, but won't deploy directly from eclipse.

I have tried updating everything and cant seem to debug the app. What causes this Segmentation Fault?

Comment: Post the Logcat output.  Someone asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418713/segmentation-fault-when-deploying-to-handset

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue.
Make sure your sdk and adt are of latest version.
If the issue still there then its due to the rom installed.

1. Some custom roms may leads to this issue.
2. Installation of busybox may lead to this issue.
3. Corrupted OS installation.

**This can be solved by wiping all data and putting stock rom back.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It helped me to avoid a similar error. In particular, my problems stemmed from the fact that I omitted a second string in my Manifest

```
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```